# Permissions for local lamp server

Tags: linux, permissions, lamp

I just set up a debian box as a local-only lamp server. I need to know how to set up permissions (and possibly ownership?) on my /var/www folder so that I can have full control over that folder from my main user account (not root/su).

I am somewhat familiar with the chmod command but if you could provide code examples that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include yourself in the www-data group and change the ownership of the directory. Example:

```
$ sudo adduser you www-data
$ sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www
$ sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www
```

Comment: This is what I'd do, though I'd prefer `sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www` to avoid adding the execute bit to files which shouldn't have it.

Comment: You are right, it was a shortcut, but do not forget to add also +x to directories, and +r to files

Comment: P.S. This might be obvious to most, but I had to log out and log back in for the permissions to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the Apache group and add yourself to the same group.
Check that the /var/www folder's group is set to the same (should be)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Wordpress users** are who struggle with this issue.
Well, I found that adding the user root to www-data can solve this problem.
You may have to try adding yourself instead of root.

```
usermod -a -G www-data root
```

You can also see a simple **three-step method** in this post below if the above post didn't work for you.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/635522/file-permission-problem-on-ubuntu-lamp-server/1187503#1187503

or,
https://www.techify.club/2019/11/09/fix-linux-lamp-server-permission-issues-ultimate-fix-2020/